# Disable special characters in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm trying to "ease" into VIM as my primary coding editor. I find that I'm still making plenty of "mistrokes" as I learn the many modes/features of VIM. While I'm in insert mode, I notice that combinations of keystrokes will produce special characters - mostly characters in non-latin alphabets.) I would like to disable this for now. Is it possible? In order words, to prevent multi-byte characters from being displayed in insert mode?

EDIT: (added example)

One example of this is when I delete a character (delete key on mac keyboard) and follow this quickly with another character. For example, delete+d produces " ﺽ " .

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Could you give us a more specific example of input keystrokes, result and expected result?

Comment: I added an example above. Thanks.

Comment: To find the bug I whan to known that is printed by command :set

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like keys not timing out as controlled by `'timeout'`, `'timeoutlen'`, `'ttimeout'` and `'ttimeoutlen'`.  You might try

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=5000 ttimeoutlen=50
```

which should cut the time vim will wait between keystrokes to see if they're the "same" (pseudo-)key down to 50ms.

The exact numbers you want would vary depending on your connection.  If you're editing over a low-bandwidth connection, you might have to bump up the 50ms to something higher if you use function keys, 6-pack, or arrow keys (anything that transmits as a sequence of characters).

Answer (score 0):

In vim, typing the two characters with a backspace between them will produce a [digraph](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html) if the [`digraph` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27digraph%27) is set. If you want to disable this, see if there is a `set digraph` in your `vimrc` and remove it.

Your terminal settings probably map the delete key to backspace.
If you don't want that, you have to [change that in the settings](http://chad.glendenin.com/macosx-backspace.html).